# Rspec for controller method in case of ternary operator in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

my controller code is as follows:

```
def create
    member_id = user_info.try(:member_id)
    message = member_id.present? ? MemberCoupon.create_by(member_id, params) : 401
    render json: {:status_code => message}, content_type: 'application/json'
end
```

Now I want to write the Rspec for this create method for all scenarios. I am new to rspec please help. Any help will be appreciated.

I tried and wrote rspec like this;

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe MemberCouponsController do
  before do
    controller.class.skip_before_filter :login_required
  end
  describe "POST #create" do
    before do
      controller.stub_chain(:user_info, :member_id).and_return("member_id")
    end

    context "when member id present" do
      it "should create coupon" do
       params = {
        "action"=>"create", 
        "controller"=>"member_coupons"
      }
        MemberCoupon.should_receive(:create_by).with("member_id", params).and_return(200)
        post 'create'
      end
    end

    context "when member id is absent" do

    end
  end
end
```

For context "when member_id is absent the rspec fails.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you have this block:

```
before do
  controller.stub_chain(:user_info, :member_id).and_return("member_id")
end
```

before both

```
context "when member id present" do
```

and

```
context "when member id is absent" do
```

So for both of them

```
MemberCoupon.create_by...
```

will be called. You should instead create different `before` blocks for each context:

```
context "when member id present" do
  before do
    controller.stub_chain(:user_info, :member_id).and_return("member_id")
  end

  ...
end

context "when member id is absent" do    
  before do
    controller.stub_chain(:user_info, :member_id).and_return(nil)
  end

  it "should not create coupon" do
    MemberCoupon.should_receive(:create_by).never
    post :create
  end
end
```